# About pinned memory in CUDA, is there an upper limit on it?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, nvidia

I wrote an application that would be benefit from pinned memory, and the best performance can be achieved when there are fairly large pinned memory.

We ordered a server, consisting of 768GB memory and I plan to allocate **~500GB** memory as pinned, is there any problem with that, since I have never allocated that much pinned memory before, so far on our servers with much smaller memory installed, I dont see any problem of allocating large chunk of memory as page-locked/pinned.

The targetting OS of my application will be both Windows server 2008 R2 and RHEL6+, CUDA version being 6.0 RC or 5.5, GPUs are tesla K20x, btw.

Answer (score 2):

There is no maximum pinned memory limit in CUDA. It is determined by the amount of main memory your machine have, the memory required by other process(OSs and applications) etc.
Sometimes, the OS puts a limit on the maximum amount of page-locked memory any process can request which has a soft limit and a hard limit. You can change the both.

Comment: Unless you use a Windows WDDM platform and driver, in which case there are both hard limits on the size of both pinned and pageable allocations. This is discussed in the platform release notes.

Comment: @talonmies I dont think there is a hard limit for the size of pinned allocations on Windows even with WDDM, do you have any reference on that, I dont see anything in the release notes mentioned that since CUDA 5.0+